# PostgreSQL getting a year from date type as integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a date and I want to get just the year from it as an integer.

Comment: a google search would've helped you.

Comment: extract(year from datecol)::int

Comment: @vkp i apologise im really new on pgsql and sql in general and i was confused with the google results as they ended up as dates or characters from extracting. all i needed was a simple integer format on top of that which i thought after seeing the suggestions

Comment: @OtoShavadze thanks a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
SELECT extract( year FROM CURRENT_DATE )::int;
```

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty simple, really...

```
SELECT year([datecolumn])      
  FROM [yourTable]
```

Since that will be nothing more than a 4-digit number, you can use it as an integer wherever you go.

Comment: There is no year function in pg.

Comment: Ah.  I saw SQL tag and went with that.

Comment: `year()` has nothing to do with SQL. It's a SQL Server flub, one of the very many ways it breaks the spec.